# How to add eventListener each separate li into each separate function?

Tags: javascript

I am using the function, to add each li into each function, using addEventListener. According to me, on click on each li, should call each separate function. how can i add the li's separately each functions?  any one can help me..?

```
window.onload = function(){

            var myLi = document.getElementById('ul').getElementsByTagName('li');

            for(i=0;i<=myLi.length;i++){
                myLi[i].addEventListener('click','call'+[i],false);
            }

            function call(){
                alert('function one called');
            }

            function call2(){
                alert('function two called');
            }

            function call3(){
                alert('function three called');
            }

        }
```

Comment: what are the different callN() functions doing? Right now it sounds to me like you'd be better off re-factoring the code so it doesn't require X number of functions to operator properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to store your functions,

```
var calls = [];

calls[0] = function() { alert("1 called"); }
calls[1] = function() { alert("2 called"); }
..
```

Then add the event listeners as,

```
myLi[i].addEventListener('click', calls[i], false);
```

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/34msm/).